# Concatenating strings to a path

Tags: perl

I'm having some trouble with concatenation on strings. I'm tring to create a path that will become a .txt file, but it always ends up as just ".txt" with no name. It ends up in the right fikder though.

This is what I'm doing:

```
open TEXT, ">/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline".$ID."/".$platformName.".txt" or die $!;
```

So I want to create the file.
    "/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline45/linux.txt"

Where am I messing this up?

Thanks!

Comment: `$ID = 45; $platformName = "linux"; print ">/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline" . $ID . "/" . $platformName . ".txt", "\n";` prints `>/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline45/linux.txt`.  So "where am I messing this up?" is "Somewhere else."

Comment: You should use the three argument open, i.e. `open my $fh, '>', "/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline45/linux.txt" or die $!;`.

Comment: The suggestions for three-arg open, lexical filehandles, parenthesis to visually disambiguate operator precedence (it's not ambiguous to Perl), and to use interpolation instead of concatenation are all orthogonal to the actual problem.  Unfortunately, the question is unanswerable unless we're given more information, because the code presented isn't technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! You are right.. it was "something else". Looks like $platformname is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You are not messing up in the snippet provided, there are several ways of forming a string including values from variables and you are using one of them (the dot-operator) correctly.

Try checking so that `$platformType` really contains what you think it, and unless you haven't already; turn warnings (and preferrably strict mode) on.

Turning warnings/strict mode on might give you details of undefined variables which would be helpful in situations such as this (ie. Is `$platformType` really the name of the variable you are looking for?)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Print the value of `$platformType` before trying to open the file and you will find that it is indeed an empty string (or just containing something weird that would explain the results you are getting).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
open TEXT, '>/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline/' . $ID . '/' . $platformName . '.txt';
```

Step 2:

```
open TEXT, ">/home/admin/www/build/logs/baseline/" . $ID . "/" . $platformName . ".txt";
```

I think like this..........